# CRC-32 oddity in PHP

Tags: php, hash, crc, crc32

Is there some specific reason why `crc32($data)` yields a completely different hash than `hash("crc32", $data)` in PHP?

Consider this code snippet (also posted online at http://ideone.com/eqbin4):

```
<?php
$data = "message";
echo(sprintf("%08x", crc32($data)) . "\n");
echo(hash("crc32", $data) . "\n");
?>
```

Output:

```
b6bd307f
c048b5b8
```

What am I getting wrong here, or is this just a PHP curiosity, using different CRC-32 computation methods for the same type of hash?

Comment: Are you on 32-bit PHP?

Comment: Version is PHP 5.5.11, x86 architecture on my local server. Not sure about the PHP version ideone.com is using, where the output is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the`crc32($d)` function is equalent to the `hash("crc32b", $d)` call, not the `hash("crc32", $d)`.

Comment: Yes, that actually seems to be the case. Thanks!

Comment: but which CRC32 is the "real" one?

Comment: I would say that the `crc32` (not `crc32b`) version is the "real" one. I *think* that is the one that is implemented as crc32 in other languages too. But I would test that to be 100% sure! :)